# Is there a way to avoid using numerous Start-Sleep's when e.g using the Restart-Computer?

Tags: powershell

I have a script where a server is renamed and then added to the domain. Something along the lines of

```
Rename-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerIP -NewName $newComputerName -LocalCredential $LocalCredential -Verbose  
Start-Sleep -s 5

Add-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerIP -DomainName $DomainName -LocalCredential $LocalCredential -Options JoinWithNewName,AccountCreate -Credential $DomainCredential -force -Verbose -Restart 

Start-Sleep -s 60
```

After renaming the server I have to add a "Start-Sleep -s 5" to ensure that the computer is not added to the domain before its ready and so on.

And after the server is in the domain I have to add a Start-Sleep -s 60 to ensure that the next part is not executed too early. I tried to use -Wait to ensure the server would wait until after restart to continue, but this fails because it's rebooting twice. Note: After the first reboot it never gets to the login screen, but powershell interpret it as being done still. The two reboots are due to a window feature being installed

Is this the correct logic to apply to the script, or is it a general way to fix problems like these?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be helpful:

use Add-Computer without -Restart parameter and after that you can use

Restart-Computer -ComputerName $ComputerIP -Wait -For PowerShell

You can also wait for -WMI or -WinRM

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

I tried this, but it seems like it establishes contact with powershell in-between the two restarts (even though it never gets close to a login screen after the first)

Also I think default in -Wait is to wait for powershell, WMI and winrm, so specifying -for powershell would pretty much only take away the "wait for WMI and winrm". Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Dont use -Wait .. But WMI and RPC both are pretty useful in this case. If we can poll them effectively.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use do-while.

So the logic would be that **start-sleep for only 1 sec** and until the condition is met. In your case the condition would be checking the server is pinging or not or some status check.
SO it means, it will wait for 1 sec each time till the System is up.

Its just the logic. You can implement according to your requirement.

```
Do { Start-sleep 1 } 
while(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computername)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good logic, but even though the computer is pingable it might not be ready to proceed with the script.

Comment: @user2121604: There is no direct way , but still you can check wmi and rpc for the same. Let me paste another set of function which can help you. Its effective.

Comment: Please refer both the answers pasted from my side. In that way, I can tell its 85% effective.

Comment: @user2121604: Accept the answers if it helps you. :)

Comment: Will do some testing tomorrow and come back

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Rename-Computer`, you can complete both rename and join with `Add-Computer` using the [NewName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/add-computer) parameter like so:

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName $Computer -NewName $newComputerName -DomainName $DomainName -LocalCredential $LocalCredential -Credential $DomainCredential
```

This simplifies your script to have only one reboot.

Comment: Also tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. The it fails in the renaming process and keeps using the wrong name. (Possibly due to powershell executing too fast)

The two reboots happens because of a windows feature being installed

Comment: What error are you getting if it's failing? Worth noting that it won't use the new name until after the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The below script polls **WMI** and **RPC** to determine when the computer is full ready, There is no direct method for doing this. YOu can write your own methods using the System.Net classes.

```
function WaitForWMI{
         Param(
               $computername
         )
         $msg='Timed out after {1:N0} seconds connecting to {0}.  Trying again'
         $starttime=[datetime]::Now
         While(!(GWMI Win32_Bios -computername $computername -ea 0)){
               Write-Host ( $msg -f $computername, $([datetime]::Now -$starttime).TotalSeconds) -fore green
         }
          Write-Host ('Host {0} conncted at {1}'  -f $computername, [datetime]::Now) -fore blue -back white
    }
```